How to lock/unlock private space in android kotlin?
I'm making a launcher app and I want to add Google's new private space feature. The official documentation says that I need to use the requestQuietModeEnabled() function but I can't figure out how to get the UserHandle that needs to be passed to it.
I've tried this code which does it for all user profiles, which only returns two profiles, but it just crashes with the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User 0 is not a profile

So, I tried using an if statement to check if the user is the private space user with  android.os.usertype.profile.PRIVATE and Intent.EXTRA_USER as said in the documentation but I couldn't get those to build.
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
fun lockPrivateSpace(context: Context) {
    val userManager = getSystemService(context, UserManager::class.java) as UserManager
    val profiles = userManager.userProfiles
    for (userInfo in profiles) {
            userManager.requestQuietModeEnabled(true, userInfo)

    }
}

